# Return Drive name to VBA in Access from batch file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, batch-file, sharepoint

I have a Batch file that maps the next available free drive letter to a network drive. I use this to map a sharepoint site and then use the documents in the shared folder in my Access database.

this is the batch file (which works perfectly to map the netwrok)

```
@echo off
for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do CD %%a: 1>> nul 2>&1 & if errorlevel 1 set freedrive=%%a:
echo %freedrive%
pause
Net Use %freedrive% "http://XYZ/" 
pause
```

I call this batch file as a shell from a form in Access VBA. So after the drive is mapped, I want to know what was the letter assigned so that I can run my MACRO which will link the tables from the databases on this newly mapped (whose letter I don't know) drive to the current operating Access file. 
I don't know how to return variables from a Batch file to a vba code and then use it for my other work.

EXTRA: I would also like to delete the mapped drive at the end when the user has finished querying or editing the tables. This would generally happen when the user decides to exit Access. I could write another batch file for this but I need to know which drive letter was used in order to delete it!

All help is highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I completely traded off the batch file with API calls for which the link is provided in the selected answer. The whole thing was integrated right in access and worked like a charm!
and the batch file code is not mine. I got it from [here](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Batch_files%3a_First_Free_Drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the system for a list of current drives. iterate letters until one does not appear in the list.

Pass that as an argument to the batch file.

Alternatively you can also replace the `net use` with calls to the API; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173011

```
Private Declare Function GetLogicalDriveStrings Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLogicalDriveStringsA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Function GetNextFreeDriveLetter() As String
    Dim buff As String, temp As Long
    buff = Space$(255)
    temp = GetLogicalDriveStrings(255, buff)
    If temp > 0 Then
        buff = vbNullChar & Left$(buff, temp)
        For temp = 67 To 90 'ascii C-Z
            If InStr(buff, vbNullChar & Chr$(temp) & ":\") = 0 Then
                GetNextFreeDriveLetter = Chr$(temp) & ":"
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. This is very useful because now I don't have to worry about sending the batch file to all the users who will access the database as VBA takes care of everything I want to do!! How did you come up with a solution so quickly? Have you done similar things before? this was awesome!

Comment: In general if a batch file can do a *thing* then so can any language (like VBA) that has access to the underlying operation system API, usually in a more elegant way.

Comment: Oh ya that makes sense. It is so much more user friendly like this even more programmer friendly!

Answer (score 1):

`Environ()` gets you the value of any environment variable. These can be found by doing the following command in the Command Prompt or Batch:

```
SET [variable=[string]]
```

If you wanted to get the value in variable, you would do:

```
Environ("variable")
```

In your particular case, from VBA:

```
MsgBox Environ("freedrive")
```

Comment: 'Environ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. this is what I got when I added the command Environ("freedrive"). And how does this return to the vba script?

Comment: @YusufN. Use `environ("freedrive")` in VBA as shown above

Comment: I created a textbox and said Text2.text = Environ("freedrive") but it always remains null. I am sorry if this is stupid, I am not a very well versed programmer in VBA or DOS...