# Drive.exists(String to select from cells range A1:A26)

Tags: excel, vba, networking

I am currently working on a macro to check if a certain drive is being used or not.
I got the code working but however it's only based on a letter drive I provide.
What I want it to do is that I want it to loop between A to Z till I find one that's not used.

```
DriveExists("D:\")
```

As you can see the ("D:\") is what I specified it to find.
What I want it to be

```
DriveExists("Cells A1:A26")
```

Can't get the code working, would appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24289311/246342 to fetch the next available drive and how to return a list of used drive letters

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub Orac()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A26")

For Each rng2 In rng1.Cells
If objFSO.driveexists(rng2.Value) Then
    MsgBox rng2 & " exists", vbExclamation
Exit For
End If
Next

End Sub
```